# Using a variable in a function

Tags: c#, variables, using

I use a dll and I haven't its source code. Somebody advised me to use a fonction of this dll like this :

```
void IDSCallback.Received(NetworkStream a)
{
    using (a)
    {
        // Some code...
    }
}
```

I don't understand the purpose of the `using`. At the end of this function, `a.Dispose()` is called so `a` is no longer usable.

So the function which called the `IDSCallback.Received()` can't use it anymore.

Why the `using` is in the function `IDSCallback.Received()` and not in the function which called `IDSCallback.Received()` ?

Comment: `a` should certainly not be disposed in this method as `Received` does not own it.

Comment: You should only use `using` on objects whose lifetime you actually want to limit. `Somebody` is wrong. Unless it *is* proper of you to close the stream as part of the `Received` message (e.g. as part of a "close" message or something), you shouldn't do that.

For the most part, it's a bad idea to use `using` on things that aren't basically local variables you've just created :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's something similar to javas [auto resource closing try-catch](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html). Take a look at the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx)

In your context you should not dispose the parameters. You should rather do it where you create it:

```
void IDSCallback.Received(NetworkStream a)
{
    //..
}
```

and where you create it:

```
using (NetworkStream  a = /* Create the stream */)
{
    IDSCallback.Received(a);
    // Do whatever else you want with it
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A using is a try/finally block to make sure that the `Dispose()` method is called on the resource. See [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx) for how it is interpreted by the compiler.

The question of whether you need to use a `using` statement or not in the `IDSCallback.Received` method depends on the contract the method has with the calling code, and, unless there is a compelling reason, it should not be disposing a resource it did not construct. As a result, there should be no `using` statement either.

The advice could have been for the code that calls `IDSCallback.Received` method to use the `using` statement so once the `NetworkStream` is no longer needed, it can be disposed off properly.